# ASP.NET MVC - Dot Net Nuke

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How we can create a application like dotnetnuke with the help of MVC. We can add modules and other things directly without modification to code.

Comment: Could you possibly elaborate? The question is fairly generic and currently the correct answer would be write it yourself based on your required needs?

Comment: I want to develope a community site with asp.net mvc. This application i want same as dotnetnuke. That I can add modules in future as per my requirememnt is that possible with asp.net mvc

Comment: Try orchardproject.net inseed of DNN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This type of question speaks volumes. Whilst you will certainly learn a lot by attempting such a project, the fact that you are asking this question suggests that there are many, many gaps in your knowledge, not the least of which is the understanding that you won't get a useful answer by asking such a question due to the fact that such an undertaking is a large endeavour composed of many subcomponents and crossing multiple disciplines. You cannot expect anyone to give you the answers you need in the space required here.

My suggestion would be to step back, fire up Visual Studio and first create a simple website with MVC; perhaps with a few features such as memberships, forums, editable pages and commenting on pages.

Once you feel comfortable with MVC and can find your way around its architecture with ease, you'll be able to start thinking about your approach to more complex problems such as building a CMS like DotNetNuke.

I would encourage you also to not build a new version of DotNetNuke just because it's what you're used to, but to look at that system and decide if that's really the best way to do things and see if there aren't ways you could improve (or completely overhaul) that type of CMS implementation.

Comment: Thanks nathan. I am doing that only

Answer (score 2):

Start looking at [Kooboo](http://www.kooboo.com/)

From the website :

> **Enterprise CMS based on ASP. NET MVC**
>
> Kooboo CMS allows you to create a professional website efficiently
>   without losing out on product quality.
>
> **Developers**
>   This Enterprise CMS system saves time and allows you the
>   freedom that you need to develop high-quality websites with a personal
>   touch.  We've streamlined the web development process. Kooboo CMS is
>   based on the ASP.NET MVC. Our easy-to-use tutorials and quick response
>   forum provide clear instruction and support to give you confidence to
>   unleash your creative potential.
>
> **Designers**
>   We give you the control that you deserve in your HTML/CSS
>   coding.  Kooboo CMS does not generate any external HTML code.  In
>   addition, we provide support and suggestions regarding HTML coding.
>
> **Individuals**
>   Create your own personal website with ease!  Visit
>   kooboostore.com to download site packages and modules, and get started
>   setting up your website with just one click!  Check in at the store
>   for weekly site package updates from community users or the Kooboo
>   team.
>
> Kooboo CMS provides fast, enterprise-level web development that is
>   very user-friendly.  We built this system as a result of not finding
>   what we were looking for in any other development packages.  Let us
>   show you how rewarding and profitable easy web development can be!

Licensing is GPL v3 with a support option.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is not any CMS built upon the MVC framework which provides the same flexability and features as DotNetNuke. This is probably due to the fact that v. 1.0 of MVC was only released 4-6 weeks ago.

Comment: People are creating several open source applications based on MVC for more then a year.

Comment: Because of the statement "We can add modules and other things directly without modification to code" to mean building an app using an existing application or development framework such as DNN. I realise there are many MVC open source applications, however I don't know of any as mature as DNN.